# How to config.get() a project variable into a task's initConfig in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

In Grunt, I have a custom multitask that extracts paths from an HTML file and uses `grunt.config.set()` to add those found paths to an array on the config called "pathsfound".

I want to use `grunt.config.get()` to access those paths so that I can use them to concat, uglify, etc.

**Gruntfile.coffee**

```
    pathfinder:
        dist:
            files: [
                expand: true
                cwd:  '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                src: '*.html'
            ]
    concat:
        dist:
            src: grunt.config.get('pathsfound')
            dest: 'stuff.js'
```

And my registered task looks like:

```
grunt.registerTask 'dist', ['pathfinder:dist', 'concat:dist']
```

However, the concat task is giving me an `TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined` error, suggesting that `grunt.config.get()` can't find the `pathsfound` variable in initConfig.

Is there any way to lazy load config variables during the initConfig phase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you've written it, the `grunt.config.get` call is executed when the config object is being built, so your variable isn't there yet.

A way to make grunt load them later is to use a template instead:

```
concat:
  dist:
    src: "<%= pathsfound.bower %>"
```

The templates are lazily expanded, just before the task is run. If the task that sets the config runs before the task that needs it, it should work.

Comment: I'm positive that I tried this at first and it didn't work for me. My guess is I mistyped the name of the variable and it failed silently as a result.

Comment: I believe you, I had my share of confusions with templates :) A very good debugging tool is to run with `--verbose`

Comment: Yeah, and `--stack``. I did both but that was after I'd replaced the template with an explicit `grunt.config.get()` call.